# Difference between dummy variable in regression and t-test - testing significant differences

Tags: multiple-regression, t-test

I am working on a multiple regression using two separate (but similar) samples. I have included both groups in the regression together without a dummy variable because there is no significant differences in the groups for all other independent and the dependent variable using a t-test. However, when I added the dummy variable into the regression model it was significant. This implies that the sample group shifts the dependent variable outcome. How can this be true if there is no significant difference between the groups for the dependent variable using a t-test?

I am wondering how best to proceed at this point - keep the groups together because there is no significant difference, or include the dummy variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you have a model that looks something like this:
$$Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X + \beta_2 D + \epsilon,$$
where $X$ is an independent variable, $D$ is the dummy variable you are unsure about including, and the $\beta$s are the coefficients you estimate. For simplicity, let's say that there is only one independent variable, so $X$ is a scalar.

When you say that there is no significant difference between the groups using a t-test, I'm assuming that you meant that a t-test comparing the means of the variables tells you that there is not a significant difference between their *means.* But the two samples could be different in other ways. Let's suppose, for example, that $E[X]=1$ and $E[Y]=2$ in both samples, but in the first sample $\beta_1 = 1$, and in the second sample $\beta_1 = 2$. If we estimate the model without the dummy variable
$$Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X + \epsilon$$
for both samples, we'll get $\beta_0 = 1$, $\beta_1 = 1$ for the first sample, and $\beta_0 = 0$, $\beta_1=1$ for the second sample. That is because, although the samples look similar just looking at them, their underlying correlational structures are different. In the case of this example, if we want to combine the two samples in a single regression, the correct specification would actually be something like
$$Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X + \beta_2 D + \beta_3 X*D + \epsilon$$
to account for the fact that both the intercept and the slope coefficients are different between the two regressions.

Of course we can't say for sure without looking at the data you're using, but the fact that the dummy is significant when you include it is probably at least an indication that the specification without the dummy is not quite right. I would play around with several different specifications, including for example the one I have written above, and see if you can tease out what the right model is. Or, if possible, it may actually be best to keep the two samples separate, since it seems like their relationships with the dependent variable are different.